# Android Memory leak with internal classes

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am facing memory leak with my android application, my recent activity which was closed is not getting released from memory. Its instance (context) is hold by ContextImpl's mOuterContext. Because of that always one instance of same activity is remaining in memory even after closing. Here is my MAT o/p.

[image]

What may be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: How is anybody supposed to find the error if you don't show us the relevant parts of your code? Anyway are you running any asynchronous code in that `Activity`? maybe a `Thread` or an `AsyncTask`? Are you passing `Context`/`Activity` references to that `Thread` or `AsyncTask`? Are you passing the `Context`/`Activity` to other components besides asynchronous ones? Do you know what a `WeakReference` is? And most of all: Are you really sure that there actually is a memory leak?

Comment: Samsung device right?

Comment: Just a strong reference to your activity context or view hierarchy.

Comment: what is your mOuterContext for BTW?  It seems it doesn't get released after finishing activity and it sounds like a member of your class but for what? You don't use it in a static way do you?

Comment: What does "even after closing" mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare Closing the activity with back button. Even after removing its previous activity (Previous activity instance count is 0 in heap dump)

Comment: @JesusS Its samsung device only, is it related to device?

Comment: @XaverKapeller There are lot of coding errors I fixed from past 2 days which are holding the reference of context like static reference in view class, eventbus not deregistered and many more.

Comment: @SandeepManne Static references? Those static references are most likely the cause of the memory leak but I can only give you definitive answer if you show us your code.

Comment: @SandeepManne **NEVER** use `static` for anything besides constants unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I removed all those by doing Memory analysis, those are straight forward as in MAT, I can see which class is holding the reference and remove the strong reference in that. Now I have huge code base, I can't a piece because I don't know what piece is causing the issue. Static references are created by other developers. I understand the problem with static.

Comment: I found this is happening only in Samsung device, today I tested by removing all code and having only blank activity with setContentView, then also it has memory leak. So I tested in nexus and found issue does not exist.